# C Linked-List Queue : What should I return when trying to dequeue an empty queue?

Tags: c, error-handling, queue

What should I return when trying to dequeue an empty queue?

My textbook tells be to return a 'key' that signals an error.

I tried :

```
Element queueEmpty()
{
    Element elem = {'!'};
    printf("Queue is empty");
    return elem;
}
```

but figured that it's not a good design since '!' is not a unique representation of an error.

(Assuming that any char data can be a valid input)

**My full code for Queue ADT & dequeue function :**

```
typedef struct
{
    char data;
} Element;

typedef struct Node *nodePtr;
typedef struct Node
{
    Element elem;
    nodePtr next;
} Node;

nodePtr front[MAX_QUEUES];
nodePtr rear[MAX_QUEUES];





Element dequeue(int i)
{
    Element elem;
    nodePtr temp = front[i];
    if(!front[i])
    {
        return queueEmpty();
    }
    elem = temp->elem;
    front[i] = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return elem;
}
```

FYI : My textbook is : "Fundamentals of Data Structures in C" by Horowitz, Sahni, Anderson-Freed

Comment: If ...:'!' is not a unique representation of an error.", then perhaps you know something *that is*. How would *we* know what that would be, when we didn't even know `!` was unacceptable until you said so?

Answer (score 1):

Why not returning a integer and using an pointer as additional output like this:

```
int dequeue (int i, Element *elem)
{
nodePtr temp = front[i];
if(!front[i])
{
    return -1; // Error parttern
}
*elem = temp->elem;
front[i] = temp->next;
free(temp);
return elem;
}
```

Calling:

```
Element elem;
if(dequeue(i,&elem) == -1)
{
 // Queue was empty
}
else
{
 // do what you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try:

1. Return an invalid `Element`. In this case the user needs to check the returned element is valid or not.
2. Throw an `exception`, when the user is trying to call dequeue operation on empty queue.

Personally I'll recommend the second way.